# When using Google Analytics to track virtual pageviews, what is the correct path name for the home (root) path?

Tags: google-analytics

The [Google Analytics documentation for tracking virtual pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) provides an example for setting the new page value:

> ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');

My use case is an (almost) single-page site where the only stats I'm interested in tracking are in query parameters from AJAX calls using the root URL, such as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/?variable=something&another_variable=something_else
```

What is the correct way to specify this? It is:

```
ga('set', 'page', '/');
```

or

```
ga('set', 'page', '');
```

or something else, such as a full path?

Answer (score 0):

You should use what `document.location.pathname` would typically show when you're on the homepage of a site - whcih is `/`

Therefore the below is the right call to make:

`ga('set', 'page', '/');`